# Accordion element makes whole page move

Tags: html, django, bootstrap-4, django-templates, mdbootstrap

When opening a long text accordion, the whole page (or the whole div) moves slightly. I attach a little video to show the problem visually [here](https://streamable.com/ntx0g1).

I have the accordions displaying information from a django template engine loop, here's the template code:

```
<div class="accordion accordion-borderless" id="accordion_{{ forloop.counter }}">
    <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="heading_{{ forloop.counter }}">
        <button
        class="accordion-button collapsed"
        type="button"
        data-mdb-toggle="collapse"
        data-mdb-target="#collapse_{{ forloop.counter }}"
        aria-expanded="false"
        aria-controls="collapse_{{ forloop.counter }}"
        >
        {{event.title}}
        </button>
        <div id="collapse_{{ forloop.counter }}" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="heading_{{ forloop.counter }}" data-mdb-parent="#accordion_{{ forloop.counter }}">
            <div class="accordion-body">
                {{event.description|safe}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What is causing that movement and how can it be solved?

Edit:

This is the raw HTML of the accordion:

```
<section class="bg-light appear-animation h-100" data-appear-animation="fadeIn">

    <div class="container border rounded-3 p-4">
        <div class="event-title">
            <h3>Halloween Party</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion accordion-borderless" id="accordion_1">
            <div class="accordion-item">
            <h2 class="accordion-header" id="heading_1">
                <button
                class="accordion-button collapsed"
                type="button"
                data-mdb-toggle="collapse"
                data-mdb-target="#collapse_1"
                aria-expanded="false"
                aria-controls="collapse_1"
                >
                
                </button>
                <div id="collapse_1" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="heading_1" data-mdb-parent="#accordion_1">
                    <div class="accordion-body">
                        <p><strong>Join the halloween party</strong></p>

<p>adadasdasd</p>

<p>adsasdasd</p>

<p>adsasdasdasd</p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p>adsadasdasdasd</p>

<p>asdasdadsads</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="container border rounded-1">Oct. 30, 2022, 6 p.m.</div>
        </div> 
    </div> 
    
    <div class="container border rounded-3 p-4">
        <div class="event-title">
            <h3>Christmas Party</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion accordion-borderless" id="accordion_2">
            <div class="accordion-item">
            <h2 class="accordion-header" id="heading_2">
                <button
                class="accordion-button collapsed"
                type="button"
                data-mdb-toggle="collapse"
                data-mdb-target="#collapse_2"
                aria-expanded="false"
                aria-controls="collapse_2"
                >
                
                </button>
                <div id="collapse_2" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="heading_2" data-mdb-parent="#accordion_2">
                    <div class="accordion-body">
                        <p>This is a Christmas party event.</p>

<p>For everybody.</p>

<p>This is a Christmas party event.</p>

<p>For everybody.</p>

<p>This is a Christmas party event.</p>

<p>For everybody.</p>

<p>This is a Christmas party event.</p>

<p>For everybody.</p>

<p>This is a Christmas party event.</p>

<p>For everybody.</p>

<p>This is a Christmas party event.</p>

<p>For everybody.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="container border rounded-1">Dec. 24, 2022, noon</div>
        </div> 
    </div> 
    
</section>
```

And in [this short video](https://streamable.com/rsij91) you can see that the whole page is moved because of the right-side scroll bar appearing. Is there any way to fix that behavior?

Comment: I'd assume it has something to do with the content's CSS, specifically their margins or widths.

Comment: Do you mean the "accordion-body" class div's CSS? I'm using MDBootstrap inside a template but haven't really modified any of the CSS just yet.

Comment: I'm thinking more the `Join the Halloween Party` and other text **inside** the accordion-body. And Bootstrap contains a **bunch** of CSS that is auto-applied, it's truly a mess somethings. Could you paste the raw HTML of the accordion instead of the template?

Comment: I edited the question with the raw HTML and another short video showing that the page is being moved by the right-side scroll bar. Any way to remove that behavior? Thank you.

Comment: The scroll bar, oof, that's the worst! **#1:** You just default set the page to a height that always shows the scroll bar. **#2:** you could hide the scroll bar all together with CSS `overflow-y:hidden` *(meh)* **#3:** You could also just default pad over `x` amount to take into account the scroll bar *(gross)*